# Creating more than one class

Tags: java, netbeans

Can someone help me by telling me how to create additional classes from the code below?
My teacher wants more than just one class for this assignment, but I made it all in one class, so I need help dividing it into more than one class, if possible. This is in Netbeans.

```
package stringfinder;

/**
 *
 * @author Christopher, Martin, Rasmus
 * @version 1.00
 */
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class StringFinder {

    public void run ()
    {
        int count = 0, countBuffer=0;
        //Enter the filepath to your desired text file.
        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Christopher\\Dropbox\\Skole\\WordDistance\\words.txt";
        BufferedReader br;
        String line = "";
        String inputSearch = "";

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {
        /**
         * The first line welcomes the user to the application
         * the second one tells the user to enter a keyword
         * @param inputSearch is the keyword the user enters in the console.
         */
            System.out.println("Welcome to Word Distance App");
            System.out.print("Enter a keyword: ");

            inputSearch = input.nextLine();

            inputSearch = inputSearch.toLowerCase();

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            try {
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String[] words = line.split(" ");

                    for (String word : words) {
                        if (word.equals(inputSearch)) {
                            count++;
                            countBuffer++;
                          }
                    } 

                    if(countBuffer > 0)
                    {
                        countBuffer = 0;
                    }

                }
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /**
         * The last two lines shows the how much the entered keyword differs from the actual word in words.txt
         * @param count how many words were found
         * @param inputSearch the previously entered keyword
         */
        System.out.println("Distance 0.  "+"("+count+" word)");
        System.out.println(inputSearch);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only is it just one class but even a single function.  Writing convoluted functions is not good style and makes re-use hard if not impossible. This is not object oriented either.

Without knowing what the purpose / context of your code is, I can identify three possible splitting points:

- Logic that deals with locating and opening the file.  It should accept the file name as a parameter and return the stream.
- Logic that deals with searching for the string.  It should take the open stream and the string to search for as a parameter and return what is now `count`.
- The controller logic that puts together these two parts.  It should obtain the file name and string to search for either as user input or – better – command line arguments, call the other two functions and then print the output.

Encapsulating the string searching logic into the `StringFinder` class and moving the other parts into a `Main` class might be a reasonable design.

As a very important rule of thumb for good design, never mix logic that defines *how* something is computed (the algorithm) with details about *what* is to be computed (parameters, user interaction, …).

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I know absolutely nothing about Java, as I can only compare it to Python, but OOP is OOP, and from reading your code, it seems you are missing the OOP part that Java is designed to MAKE you do.

If it were me:

I would try and turn the Files with the strings themselves into file Instances/Objects from their own class

```
public class FileClass{

insertYourStringFileCodeHere


}
```

Answer (score -1):

create a second file SecondClass.java in the same folder as StringFinder.java

In it add:

```
package stringfinder;


public class SecondClass{

// some code
    public void someMethod(){
    }

}
```

Then within StringFinder.run()

```
SecondClass obj = new SecondClass();
obj.someMethod();
```